# Can I connect pin 11 of TL084 to ground? I mean, are there the consequences?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc

I wonder if it is possible to connect pin 11 of a TL084 to ground to avoid having two sources.

I need to compare two signals:

Signal 1: This is a DC 9V source. (this goes to + terminal of Opamp)

Signal 2: When a switch is on this is 12 V(DC) when switch is off I think there is no signal. (this goes to - terminal of Opamp)

Comment: You should link to the datasheet for us, and specify the package for clarity.

Comment: Why not just use a MOSFET? Why the comparison to 9V?

Comment: What I need is to know when I am using or not a battery backup, so I am sending the 9V voltage of my backup battery and it is compare with the main soruce 12 V. Do you have a much better idea. I need to send the result of this comparison or something to a microcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the DIP package (Vcc- on pin 11).

You can use this op-amp with a single sided supply for your application (using it as a comparator between other positive signals).

The datasheet shows a number of examples using the op-amps in single sided mode (Vcc- connected to ground).
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos081i/slos081i.pdf#page=16

Bop Pease put together a great reference for op-amp circuits when he worked at National (which was bought by TI).  I'd recommend reading [AN-31](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf).

Comment: Please explain what is in the links you use. A good answer should have most of the information in the answer itself, so it doesn't become useless when the links go away.

Comment: I edited the answer, adding my assumptions and a little more info about the links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the TL084 - a quad op-amp: -

[image]

From you mentioning pin 11 it has to be the 14 pin package because the quad package is a NC (no connect) on pin 11.

> I wonder if it is possible to connect pin 11 of a TL084 to ground

Providing that pin 4 is connected to a more positive voltage between 10V and 36 V (absolute maximum) higher, yes. If you don't connect pin 4 then the device won't function.

> Signal 1: This is a DC 9V source. (this goes to + terminal of Opamp)
>   Signal 2: When a switch is on this is 12 V(DC) when switch is off I
>   think there is no signal. (this goes to - terminal of Opamp)

Given your question about pin 11 it's reasonable to assume you are talking about the input pins Vin+ and Vin-. Yes you can connect those voltages to those pins but you'll need a positive supply on pin 4 that is at least +16V to guarantee the input (the 12V one) remains within the common mode range of the input (see data sheet). You might get away with a +12V supply on pin 4 but this is by no means guaranteed.

Additionally, for the 12V input you'll need a pull-down resistor to some voltage slightly above that of pin 11. A +4V will supply will gurantee this and again, this is so that the circuit obeys the common mode input voltage range rules in the data sheet.